Flutter - android login stuck
I have a problem in a prod flutter project. I took it over from another developer. I made the required changes, few new page and label changes etc., I haven't touched anything regarding login, firebase etc.
However the problem is when I lunch the app either locally or release the appbundle login stuck. If I type in a wrong password it gives back that either email or password incorrect, if I type in correctly its stuck infinitely, no error nothing.
I am afraid it might have to do something with the fact I took over the project from other dev, I created my own debug key and added the SHA1 and SHA256 to firebase, for release I asked the previous dev for the his jks file that I added to the android root.
Someone any suggestion what should I do?
I/flutter ( 4508):  Dispatched LoadAppEvent
I/flutter ( 4508): Checking connection...
I/flutter ( 4508):  Dispatched CheckLoggedInEvent
I/flutter ( 4508):  Dispatched FetchUserEvent
E/SurfaceSyncer( 4508): Failed to find sync for id=0
W/Parcel  ( 4508): Expecting binder but got null!
D/TrafficStats( 4508): tagSocket(145) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
D/TrafficStats( 4508): tagSocket(141) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
D/EGL_emulation( 4508): app_time_stats: avg=18.10ms min=7.05ms max=47.70ms count=56
D/EGL_emulation( 4508): app_time_stats: avg=17.51ms min=14.57ms max=67.20ms count=58
I/OneSignal( 4508): Device registered, UserId = 12c8d4d0-a8cd-4022-a473-64f6b2d2b866
D/EGL_emulation( 4508): app_time_stats: avg=16.66ms min=14.48ms max=20.19ms count=60

D/EGL_emulation( 4508): app_time_stats: avg=16.66ms min=14.48ms max=20.19ms count=60
This is the part that keeps logging for infinite..

Does this prblm occurs for release that is uploaded to playstore? Or does it occurs for release that hasn't been uploaded to playstore?

@Ultranmus it appears for everything currently, If I open an android emulator and run flutter run on it, it does the same thing, I edited the post with the logs I see. If I quit the emulator after it stuck and relaunch flutter run without running flutter clean, it of course trying to fetch the user and stuck without actually opening any page.

Then the problem is in login part itself. Can you add the login code. The log event is default event so it is not related to your error. It means nothing is running when trying to attempt login. The possibility might be that login is working and after login the further processing is not done. Add the login code for further assistance.

I managed to solve it. I added many prints in there and it turned out the the fetchUser's return was failing as it was using the  class that had multiple null check error in there, so on android the user didn't actually return..
I do not understand how didn't this cause any error previously and why only on android...
At least problem located and sorted.
